# .FindNext doesn't "wrap around" when the value is found in a merged cell

Tags: excel, vba

So, while I was answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56780924/a-way-to-find-a-string-within-merged-cells/56788259#56788259), I found myself having to deal with what seems to be quite a peculiar bug.

In short, when searching for all the occurrences of a string in a worksheet, if there's only one occurrence which is found in a merged cell and this cell has been constructed by merging cells from different rows, then `.FindNext` doesn't wrap around as [it is supposed to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext).

So if the first (and only) occurrence of the keyword is found in a cell that has been constructed by merging together 2 cells of the same column, then `.FindNext` will return `Nothing`.

The weird part is that it will work as expected if there are more than one occurrences or if the cell has been constructed by merging cells of the same row.

I have dealt with the issue by introducing a check for `Nothing`, but I am very curious to know why this happens.

Is it a bug? Am I missing something?

Here's the code for the sake of completion:

```
Sub main()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
Debug.Print numOfOccurrences("test", wbk) 'call the search function and print the number of occurrences to the immediate window

End Sub

Public Function numOfOccurrences(keyword As String, wb As Workbook) As Long

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim found As Range
Dim count As Long
Dim firstOccurence As String
count = 0

For Each sht In wb.Worksheets 'loop through sheets
    Set found = sht.Cells.Find(what:=keyword) 'search for the first occurrence if any
    If Not found Is Nothing Then 'if the keyword is found once, then we need to search for more occurrences
        firstOccurence = found.Address 'store the address of the first occurence
        Do
            Set found = sht.Cells.FindNext(found) 'search for the next occurrence in the same sheet
            count = count + 1 'keep track of the number of occurences
        If found Is Nothing Then
            GoTo DoneFinding    'this deals with what seems to be a bug when using .FindNext with merged cells
        End If
        Loop Until found.Address = firstOccurence 'repeat until the search goes full circle back to the first occurrence
    End If
DoneFinding:
Next sht
numOfOccurrences = count

End Function
```

Comment: @JvdV The code as it is right now does work fine. Try commenting  out the part with the GOTO where I check if found is Nothing ;)

Comment: @JvdV well theoretically the only way that .FindNext would return Nothing, would be if the values of the cells were being changed during the execution. Since they are not being changed the .FindNext should make a full circle and the second check (where goto takes place) wouldn’t be necessary...If you still can’t reproduce it after removing this part then I’m probably missing something :/ thanks for looking into it though

Comment: I have now been able to reproduce the error, very strange, I'll look into it, but probably a bug. Im curious :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen, Excel treats a merged area as a single cell so FindNext wouldn't find another cell present if there was only one merged area with the value. You can access the full range address though by using Range.MergeArea

Here is a generic FindAll function which will pull back merged areas within a range if you wish...

```
Private Function FindAll(What, _
    Optional SearchWhat As Variant, _
    Optional LookIn, _
    Optional LookAt, _
    Optional SearchOrder, _
    Optional SearchDirection As XlSearchDirection = xlNext, _
    Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False, _
    Optional MatchByte, _
    Optional SearchFormat, _
    Optional IncludeMerged As Boolean = False) As Range

    'LookIn can be xlValues or xlFormulas, _
     LookAt can be xlWhole or xlPart, _
     SearchOrder can be xlByRows or xlByColumns, _
     SearchDirection can be xlNext, xlPrevious, _
     MatchCase, MatchByte, and SearchFormat can be True or False. _
     Before using SearchFormat = True, specify the appropriate settings for the Application.FindFormat _
     object; e.g. Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "General;-General;""-""" _
     Set IncludeMerged to 'True' to include all cells within a merged area

    Dim SrcRange As Range
    If IsMissing(SearchWhat) Then
        Set SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Range Then
        Set SrcRange = IIf(SearchWhat.Cells.Count = 1, SearchWhat.Parent.UsedRange, SearchWhat)
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Worksheet Then
        Set SrcRange = SearchWhat.UsedRange
    Else: SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    End If
    If SrcRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    'get the first matching cell in the range first
    With SrcRange.Areas(SrcRange.Areas.Count)
        Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With

    Dim CurrRange As Range: Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=FirstCell, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
        SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)

    If Not CurrRange Is Nothing Then
        Set FindAll = IIf(IncludeMerged = True, CurrRange.MergeArea, CurrRange)
        Do
            Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=CurrRange, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
            SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)
            If CurrRange Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If Application.Intersect(FindAll, CurrRange) Is Nothing Then
                Set FindAll = Application.Union(FindAll, IIf(IncludeMerged = True, CurrRange.MergeArea, CurrRange))
            Else: Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: The thing is that .FindNext should always make a full circle and go back to the first occurrence. So if there’s only one occurrence .FindNext should always find the exact same cell over and over again, that is the first (and only) one. And in fact that’s exactly what it does in all other cases apart from when the cell has been constructed by merging cells from different rows and if the occurrence is **only** one...merged cells from different columns work just fine...